# User Defined Fields storage in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking at building a system which will include user created fields which will use Postgresql as the database. I've read that the EAV model for this isn't great and that a jsonb column to store the custom fields will be the best route.

I want the user to be able to build their own queries to the data as well so is the best way to go to store the custom field names in a table and store the actual data in the jsonb column, that way when it comes to building the queries the webapp can query the custom fields table for a reference as to what fields are available and their types?

Tickets

- ID
- WhenCreated
- LastUpdated
- CustomProperties {JSON B column, key value pairs where the key names will be stored in the custom fields table}

Customfields

- ID
- FieldName
- WhenCreated
- FieldTypeID

FieldTypes

- ID
- FieldTypeName {String, Date, etc}

Comment: I'd go for the JSON solution.

Comment: Depends on size of values, number of different attributes, how many values you need to store, what types the values have, and what kind of queries (with joins?) the user needs to do (and how often they run and how fast they need to be). You can use EAV, JSON, or even dynamically created table columns per attribute.

Comment: The question lacks focus. Concentrate on the important and frequent SQL statements and choose the design that makes them work well. Don't forget to consider the option of regular database tables that get created on the fly. Don't let the users construct arbitrary queries, that is a recipe for unhappiness. Force them to specify a search value for at least one selective column that is indexed.